# Flex Direction component settings

Tags: html, css, flexbox, carousel

I am newbie about css and html design. I use flex in my bootstrap design. 
I set the flex to sort the components from left to right direction.
As on the [this](http://demo.grandnode.com/) site.

**I want to shrink the slider to the right and place another component on the left side**. I tryed to removing this line over **#GrandCarousel**.

```
element.style {
    /* left: -396.5px; */
}
```

how can I make this feature

Comment: please read tag description before using: *flex4* has nothing to do with flexbox

Comment: I'm lil bit confused about the requirement. Can you draw a wireframe or something showing how you wanted the layout exactly and post it here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right i have accepted correction of the tag

Comment: @AjayVarghese yes i have edited my question according your suggestion

Comment: @Paulie_D i have edited my question is it understandable now

Comment: Please upvote my question if it is right and understandable..

Comment: @emrahaktas Is this what you meant ?? https://ibb.co/DLZdkcC

Comment: @Ajay Varghese yes this is what i want if you answer the question then i will accept thank you

Comment: @emrahaktas I have posted the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two div inside #GrandCarousel div. Let's call them left-section and right-section. Give them `width: 50%;` Put all the current contents of #GrandCarousel div to the right-section. After this you might face issues in image alignment inside slider. You will have to adjust them according to how you need them to appear. Refer below HTML, CSS code to understand better.

HTML

```
 <div id="GrandCarousel" class="banner-container">
    <div class="left-section">

         // Left section contents

    </div>
    <div class="right=section">
        // Move GrandCarousel contents to here
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .banner-container {
     display: flex;
 }

 .left-section,
 .right-section {
     width: 50vw;
 }

 .right-section {
     position: relative; // To contain all carousel contents inside right-section
 }
```